# apache2.4 permission denied

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I use mod_wsgi to connect flask web application.

But now I see this error log.

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/services
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:443>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/services/was/cash/cash.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess cash user=wasd group=operators  processes=16 threads=16 display-name=%{GROUP} 
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIProcessGroup cash

    Alias /static /home/services/was/cash/static
    <Directory  /home/services/was/cash/ >
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Such as httpd-vhosts.conf, I write `Require all granted`.

and the related directories below:

```
[wasd@xxx ~]$ cd /home/service/
[wasd@xxx service]$ ls -al 
total 28
drwxr-xr-x. 4 wasd  operators 4096 Jun 29 17:07 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root  root      4096 Jun 29 14:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 3 mysql dba       4096 May 13 14:58 mysql
drwxr-xr-x  3 wasd  operators 4096 Jun 29 16:15 was
[wasd@xxx service]$ 


[wasd@xxx was]$ ls -al      
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 17:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 17:39 cash
[wasd@xxx was]$ 

drwxr-xr-x 7 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 17:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 16:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 16:41 commons
drwxr-xr-x 2 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 16:41 lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wasd operators   47 Jun 29 16:41 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 16:41 static
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wasd operators  969 Jun 29 16:41 cash_base.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wasd operators 1067 Jun 29 16:41 cash.config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wasd operators  131 Jun 29 16:41 cash.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wasd operators  149 Jun 29 16:41 cash.wsgi
drwxr-xr-x 2 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 16:41 templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 wasd operators 4096 Jun 29 17:25 views
[wasd@xxx cash]$
```

why generate error message? how to solve this problem?

change configuration? httpd.conf?

Comment: Did you deliberately leave out the ServerName directive from the VirtualHost in your question? Without a ServerName directive and the host name, it wouldn't even match that VirtualHost. None of the SSL directives are listed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured:

```
  <Directory  /home/services/was/cash/ >
```

But you showed:

```
  [wasd@xxx ~]$ cd /home/service/
  [wasd@xxx service]$ ls -al
```

two options:

```
  mv /home/service /home/services
```

or

```
  <Directory  /home/service/was/cash/ >
```

Mind the service**s** vs. service